# Compile SASS and @import from node_modules

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I'try to compile sass to css and importing a css-file from `node_modules/purecss/build/pure.css` therefore my sass file look like:

```
@import '~purecss/build/pure.css';
```

and my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "build_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:sass": "node-sass --include-path=node_modules Private/Stylesheets/main.scss Public/Style/main.css",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "purecss": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried it with `--include-path=node_modules` and `--include-path node_modules` and `--include-paths node_modules` but it doesn't work?

Anybody an idea?

Comment: your solution is correct (such as mine: ```@import "~prismjs/themes/prism.css";```\) if your webpack cannot find your file - check for typos in its path

Answer (score 12):

You need an importer.

For the format you're using with `~`, you could use [node-sass-package-importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-package-importer).
Then run sass with the `--importer` flag like this:

```
node-sass --importer node_modules/node-sass-package-importer/dist/cli.js source/app.sass dest/app.css
```

Another option without the `~` is [node-sass-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-import).
And the code is:

```
node-sass --importer node_modules/node-sass-import source/app.sass dest/app.css
```